# Do multiple miners contribute to mining the same block even if they are not in the same pool

Tags: mining-theory, majority-attack

Assuming that this is reliable, according to an [article on investopedia on the 51 percent attack](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/51-attack.asp):

> 51% attack refers to an attack on a blockchain – usually bitcoin's, for which such an attack is still hypothetical – by a group of miners controlling more than 50% of the network's mining hashrate, or computing power. **The attackers would be able to prevent new transactions from gaining confirmations**, allowing them to halt payments between some or all users.

Does the above bold line imply that all the miners are required to provide their confirmation for a transaction to be added to the blockchain?

I was under the impression that even an individual could, if he completes the proof of work first, cause the addition of the block to the blockchain? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was under the impression that even an individual could, if he completes the proof of work first, cause the addition of the block to the blockchain? What am I missing here?

That it could happen that 2 blocks are found at the same time. Which usually causes the network to split into two chains, ( One part of the network is going to build/find a new hash based on block y, and the other part of the network is trying to find a new valid hash based on block X.).

Whoever finds Block Z first creates the longest chain and thus invalidating the shorter one. ( Miners who build on block Y find block Z so now block X ( which is the shortest chain) gets orphaned )= now invalid.

The same principle applies to a 51% attack, since you have majority hashpower you will always (hypothetically) find a valid hash faster then the other chain which has 49% hashpower.

In that case, no individual ( unless the individual owns 51% of the hashpower) is going to be able to "mine" a block/(or rather, - get a block added to the longest/valid chain).

Your title is something else then your question,

> Do multiple miners contribute to mining the same block even if they are not in the same pool

Well, yes, if there's only 1 chain, every miner is going to be building upon that chain, which means they'll all be looking for a block ( or rather a hash) that is going to be valid on that chain ( basically the next block?)

I wouldn't use contribute though, it's not like they share their hashpower, but they do indeed share the same goal. -> Finding a block with a valid hash that is valid on the current chain.